# Unity - Apply force to gameobject of child of a child

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, gameobject

I am trying to figure out how to apply force to a child object. In the image provided, I have a cube with two cylinders as circled in the image. What I want to accomplish is applying force to the end of the nozzles so that it would make the ship gameobject rotate. Am I going about this all wrong and should instead be applying a rotate to the ship itself or is adding a discrete force to the nozzles good for causing rotation of the overall ship object?

[image]